# Setting up a JPanel in a JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

So, I've been working to redo my code so that the painting is all done in a JPanel instead of a JFrame so I can do some very much needed image buffering.

I've scoured StackOverflow and I've googled my fingers raw and I thought I had it set up right, but it's not working. I just get a blank white screen and some error script in the terminal. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class RacerDoom extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 640;
    int counter = 0;
    Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH/9,HEIGHT);
    Rectangle right = new Rectangle((WIDTH/9)*8,0,WIDTH/9,HEIGHT);
    Rectangle top = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT/9);
    Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(0,(HEIGHT/9)*8,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    Rectangle center = new Rectangle((int)((WIDTH/9)*2.5),(int)((HEIGHT/9)*2.5),(int)((WIDTH/9)*4),(HEIGHT/9)*4);
    Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,HEIGHT/2,WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);
    Rectangle finishtop = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,(HEIGHT/2)-HEIGHT/9,(int)((WIDTH/9)*1.5),HEIGHT/70);
    //Starting lines
    Rectangle startO = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,HEIGHT/2,(int)((WIDTH/9)*1.5)/2,HEIGHT/140);
    public RacerDoom() {
        //create JFrame
        super("Racer Doom Squared");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        panel = new MainPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        //set up Game countdown timer
        final Timer timer=new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(counter>=10) {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                else{
                   counter++;
                   }
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
        });

        //start timer
        timer.start();
    }
    private class MainPanel extends JPanel {
        public MainPanel() {
            super();
        }
    //draw graphics
        @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        //boundaries
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(left.x,left.y,left.width,left.height);
        g.fillRect(right.x,right.y,right.width,right.height);
        g.fillRect(top.x,top.y,top.width,top.height);
        g.fillRect(bottom.x,bottom.y,bottom.width,bottom.height);
        g.fillRect(center.x,center.y,center.width,center.height);
        //start line
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(startO.x,startO.y,startO.width,startO.height);
        //finish line
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(finishtop.x,finishtop.y,finishtop.width,finishtop.height);
        //p1
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fill3DRect(p1.x,p1.y,p1.width,p1.height,true);
        //HUD
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Font f = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 24);
        g.setFont(f);
        g.drawString("Boosts: "+p1Boost,(WIDTH-(WIDTH/6)),(HEIGHT-(int)(HEIGHT/1.1)));
        g.drawString("Time: "+(10-counter),540,100);
    }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        new RacerDoom();
    }
}
```

The error script:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
>
> at RacerDoom.(RacerDoom.java:46)
>
> at RacerDoom.main(RacerDoom.java:232)

I'm quite sure I'm just an idiot and the answer is probably giving me the middle finger in the error message, but it's still Greek to me. But even (especially?) idiots need help.

Comment: It's not "some error script", it's a NullPointerException. Look at the line and try to figure out why one of the variables is null. This is not rocket science but does involve getting your fingers dirty. Check all the variables used on that line (which line is it?), and first off see which is null.

Comment: My apologies. I should have searched the web for what that error meant before posting here.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. It's very difficult to "study" traditionally when you work 60+ hours a week. I study by reading books and looking for help with problems from the online community. It's no different than a student seeking help from a teacher, I just don't have the benefit of a classroom. But arguing here is not appropriate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is pretty simple:

```
getContentPane().add(panel);

panel = new MainPanel();
panel.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
```

You're adding the panel to the widow *before* the panel is actually created. Try rearranging it like this:

```
panel = new MainPanel();
panel.setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Comment: Could I ask you to help me with code which I posted below? It is so simple code but I don't understand exception which I have got. When I google it it ony shows mistakes with not innstantiating vairable. I made instance and it doesnt work. So I doesn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe line 46 is:

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

At that point, you haven't created the panel yet, so it is null. You [can't add a null component to a container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29). Remove that line; your later `this.getContentPane().add(panel);` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException occurs because you try to add not initialized variable panel:

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

You have to first initialize this variable, and than add it to getContentPane()